# columnconfigure and rowconfigure tkinter page frames

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk

class program(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args,**kwargs)

        self.title("Staff Management System")
        self.geometry("1280x720")
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}

        #frame that will hold all the elements
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.grid(row=1,column=0,)

        for i in range(128):
            container.columnconfigure(i,weight=1)

        for i in range(128):
            container.rowconfigure(i,weight=1)
    
        #listing frames (pages) to be controlled
        for F in (homePage, staffLogin):
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = "nsew")
        
        self.show_frame(staffLogin)

    def show_frame(self, page):
        frame = self.frames[page]
        frame.tkraise()

class homePage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent,*args, **kwargs)

        self.controller = controller

        promotionsButton = tk.Button(self, text="Promotions", height = 4)
        promotionsButton.grid(row=1, column = 128, sticky='w')

        staffLoginButton = tk.Button(self, text="Staff Login", width = 50, height = 20)
        staffLoginButton.grid(row=1, column=1)

        managerLoginButton = tk.Button(self, text="Manager Login", width = 50, height = 20)
        managerLoginButton.grid(row=1,column=2)

class staffLogin(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.controller = controller

        userIDLabel = tk.Label(self, text = "UserID:")
        userIDInput = tk.Entry(self, width=50, font=("Helvectia",16))
        userIDLabel.grid(sticky="W", row=67,column=59)
        userIDInput.grid(row=67, column=60)

        userPasswordLabel = tk.Label(self, text = "Password:")
        userPasswordInput = tk.Entry(self,width=50, font=("Helvectia",16))
        userPasswordLabel.grid(sticky="W", row=70, column=59)
        userPasswordInput.grid(row=70, column=60)

        loginButton = tk.Button(self, text="Login", height=2, width=7)
        loginButton.grid(sticky="E",row = 71, column=60)

thing = program()
thing.mainloop()
```

im trying to use the container column and row configure methods in order to create 128 'boxes' that i am able to grid widgets in for each of my pages. However, it doesn't work when i run the program, when i try passing 'parent' instead of 'self' when i create my widgets in my different pages, my show_frame function doesnt work and instead it displays the widgets from both of my pages at the same time.

Comment: Everything that goes into `container` is at row=0, column=0, so configuring the other 127 rows and columns was pointless.  Each page is a separate Frame, you would have to repeat the `rowconfig()`/`columnconfig()` calls for each one if you want it to apply to their contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `rowconfigure` and `columnconfigure` on the container, but the container only has a single row and a single column that is used to hold each "page". You need to be calling those methods on each page rather than on the container.

```
class homePage():
    def __init__(self, parent, controller, *args, **kwargs):
        ...

        for i in range(128):
            self.columnconfigure(i,weight=1)

        for i in range(128):
            self.rowconfigure(i,weight=1)
```